# IBM Cloud Power on and off trigger not working

Tags: function, triggers, cloud, websphere, action

I follow the https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/how-to-schedule-a-vsi-power-on-and-off-using-ibm-cloud-functions  tutorial to configure the power on and off but its not working and giving following error.

Results:

```
{
  "error": "The action did not return a dictionary."
}
```

Logs:

```
[
  "2021-05-10T17:30:02.723667Z    stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):",
  "2021-05-10T17:30:02.723705Z    stderr: File \"pythonrunner.py\", line 88, in run",
  "2021-05-10T17:30:02.723709Z    stderr: exec('fun = %s(param)' % self.mainFn, self.global_context)",
  "2021-05-10T17:30:02.723713Z    stderr: File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module>",
  "2021-05-10T17:30:02.723716Z    stderr: File \"__main__.py\", line 7, in main",
  "2021-05-10T17:30:02.723720Z    stderr: namejson = json.loads(name)",
  "2021-05-10T17:30:02.723723Z    stderr: File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py\", line 348, in loads",
  "2021-05-10T17:30:02.723727Z    stderr: 'not {!r}'.format(s.__class__.__name__))",
  "2021-05-10T17:30:02.723731Z    stderr: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'NoneType'",
  "2021-05-10T17:30:02.724Z       stderr: The action did not initialize or run as expected. Log data might be missing."
]
```

Could anyone suggest How to achieve this task.

Comment: What exactly did you do, and what does "not working" mean?

Comment: i am trying to auto start and off the server as per above link but giving me following error.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give enough information for someone else to recreate the issue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe please see  now

Comment: @jonrsharpe all the step is given on following link.
 https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/how-to-schedule-a-vsi-power-on-and-off-using-ibm-cloud-functions

just follow all the steps and clicked on invoke action. After clicking on it , its gives above error.